# Can't find the radix to solve this equation

Tags: number-systems

I am trying to solve the equation
$$
3894937908247641871050398074967894254 = 764008325721660_x$$

Here is my attempt
$$
7x^{14} + 6x^{13} + 4x^{12} + 0x^{11} + 0x^{10} + 8x^9 + 3x^8 + 2x^7 + 5x^6 + 7x^5 + 2x^4 + 1x^3 + 6x^2 + 6x + 0 - 3894937908247641871050398074967894254 = 0$$

Wolfram Alpha gave $x = 357.412$ but when I solve for $x$ I get $6.75367976499\times 10^{31}$

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: @GFauxPas * is multiplication, ** is exponentiation

Comment: I figured it out, but it's not standard notation. Use `a \cdot x^n` or `a \times x^n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer $x=357.412$ is only an approximation to six significant digits.
That is, all you know from what Alpha told you is that 
$357.4115 \leq x < 357.4125$.

So if you just look at the leading term of your polynomial,
the exact value could be anywhere between
$7 \times 357.4115^{14}$ and $7 \times 357.4125^{14}$.
The difference between these two numbers has magnitude greater than
$1.5 \times 10^{32}$, so you should not be surprised if you find
an error of about $6.75 \times 10^{31}$ in your calculation.

And that is even without considering whether the calculation of the
polynomial is done with $37$ significant digits, which is what you
would need in order to have an answer accurate to the nearest integer.

Comment: So an initially small difference becomes giant when _. What is this effect called? Exponential growth?

Comment: It's mostly the exponential growth of $357.412^n$ that makes the difference so large in the end. The numbers $357.4115$ and $357.4125$ differ by only a small fraction of a percent, and even after raising to the 14th power the percentage difference is still small, but it's a small percentage of a _really big number_ $(7 \times 357.412^{14} > 3 \times 10^{36}),$ and the "bigness" of that number completely overwhelms the "smallness" of the percentage.